# how to don't have the same bg 2 times in a row in this random background js

Tags: javascript, math, random, background, probability

I've a problem with the same bg js as the last question; this is the js :

```
ChangeIt();
function ChangeIt()
{
    var totalCount = 12;
var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
document.body.background ='http://adventureofucm.com/OtherSites/image_background/'+num+'.jpg';
}
```

Cause I know a very little few thing of js I'm asking you if you could give a look at the js and help me find a solution to doesn't display the same bg 2 times in a row, that's all. Hope you answer me soon or just comment if you need more details or other things.
EDIT : after googling for a solutions with the local storage I found a few interesting things but I still don't have the knowledge to edit the js, anyone who can help me just a couple of mins ?

Comment: If the script is executing each time the page loads then it has no way of knowing what picture the previous page loaded. If you want different pictures on each load then you need something like local storage or session storage where you can store the picture chosen so that on the next page load you can retrieve that value again and make sure to load a different pic.

Comment: mmmh, ok. So I need to use the local storage, I have no problem with this, just don't know how to do this, could you help me with this if not a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
function ChangeIt() {

  var HasStorage, PreviousPic, totalCount, num;

  //test if browser supports local storage
  if (typeof (localStorage) === 'object') {
     HasStorage = true;

     //get the previous picture name in the storage, if any
     PreviousPic = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('Previous'), 10);
  }

  totalCount = 12;
  num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );

  //if there's a previous pic in storage then get a different one this time
  if (PreviousPic) {
      while (num === PreviousPic) {
          num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
      }
  }

  //store the pic used this load
  if (HasStorage) {
      localStorage.setItem('Previous', num);
  }

  document.body.background ='http://adventureofucm.com/OtherSites/image_background/'+num+'.jpg';
}
```

Comment: woah, that's exactly what I needed! just tryed it, works great, also image load faster after your first visit, I think i couldn't find anything better, seriously, tnx a lot :)

Comment: On a side note, you could also use cookies to store the info; that would make the functionality work in all browser, including the ones that don't support HTML5.

Comment: mmmh, not so sure, the site wouldn't works without html5 I think, at least not the entire site, so I prefear use local storage, also cause I don't like cookies so much, but tnx a lot for the think :)